# Apache nutch 1.9 database

Tags: database, apache, solr, nutch

I have set up nutch 1.9 with solr properly. Now I would like to retrieve this data via java into a program, to analyse and display the data. At them moment I can query the data with solr. However, I cannot find any further information about the underlying database which is used by nutch and how to retrive data.

Any recommendations, how that can be done?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can see your data already indexed in Solr, then you do not need to retrieve any thing from Nutch. What you need right now is the right Solr client to interact with Solr. The client will query Solr and parse responses.

Since you are going to use Java, you should use [SolrJ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj).

Comment: Is it also possible to connect to the nutch db directly? Is there sth like a jdbc connection?

Comment: If you want to connect to Nutch directly, then you should use Nutch 2.x version. It uses a database (MySql, HBase, Cassandra) as a storage engine. Hence, you can query these databases and get Nutch raw data. But, why do you want to access the raw data? I am carious here.

Comment: Thx for your answer! I would like to parse the html to retrieve some specific fields, and I guess that is stored in nutch, or am I wrong?

Comment: If that is the case, then you could try to write a new IndexingFilter, Nutch supplies indexing filters with the crawl datum and parsed content of any fetched url. You could use it to retrieve whatever you want. May I know what you want to retrieve exactly; probably there is a plugin for it already implemented.

Comment: The plan is to retrieve listing data from different job portals. Was such a plugin made?(1) How can someone code up a plugin?(2) Is there a plugin repository, where I can browse all the plugins?(3)

Comment: No plugin to do that. Please read [here](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/PluginCentral) on how to write a new plugin. It might help to see [this plugin](http://www.atlantbh.com/precise-data-extraction-with-apache-nutch/)

Comment: Thx for your answer! Is there sth like a repository for plugins, where I can have a look into its code? What are some popular plugins?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61860/discussion-between-ameertawfik-and-vivien).